# mysql Select the sum of occurances of first alphabetical character

Tags: mysql

Hi what i need to do is create a select statement which outputs the sum of the first character in a field within the table so the output would look something like

```
A,12
B,0
C,20
D,14
E,0
ect...
```

The table is called contacts, in the above there was 12 occurrences of people whose names begin with the letter A and there was 0 occurences of letter B.

I hope i have explained this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the result to display the missing letters, you need to manually generate all letters (eg. using subquery)

```
SELECT  a.Letter, 
        COUNT(u.Name) AS TotalCount
FROM
        (
            SELECT 'A' Letter UNION ALL
            SELECT 'B' Letter UNION ALL
            SELECT 'C' Letter UNION ALL
            -- until Z
            SELECT 'Z' Letter 
        ) AS a
        LEFT JOIN userList u
            ON a.Letter = LEFT(u.Name, 1)   -- <== column name
GROUP   BY a.Letter
ORDER   BY a.Letter
```

Comment: thanks but how do i add a where clause to userlist but still maintain the zero letters, i tried adding where u.verified=1 and B disapears

Comment: you should add it on `ON` clause. eg `ON a.Letter = LEFT(u.Name, 1) AND u.verified=1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select substr(name, 1,1), count(*) from contacts group by substr(name, 1,1)
```

Comment: What about the letters in the alphabet which have a count of zero, like i showed in my example for letter B, i need to get these also?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
select 
left(UPPER(firstname),1) as initial , 
count(*) as tot from users 
group by initial ;
```

UPDATE as you want to show the chars which are not there in the list you may need a look up table as well and then join with the look up table. The lookup table will only have the alphabets

```
select 
a.alpha,
coalesce(b.tot,0)  as total
from alphabets a
left join
(
  select
  left(UPPER(firstname),1) as initial , 
  count(*) as tot from users 
  group by initial
)b
on b.initial = a.alpha
;
```

OR

```
select 
a.alpha,
count(u.firstname) as tot
from 
alphabets a 
left join users u on a.alpha = left(UPPER(u.firstname),1)
group by a.alpha
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58679/11)**

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this will help.

```
SELECT LEFT(firstname,1) as character, COUNT(1) as totalCount 
FROM contacts
GROUP BY initial ORDER BY firstname;
```

Answer (score 0):

The hard way also

```
  SELECT
 'A' as letter , 
  count(*) as total FROM totalCount
  WHERE left(UPPER(firstname),1)='A'
  UNION
  SELECT
  'B' as letter , 
  count(*) as total FROM totalCount
  WHERE left(UPPER(firstname),1)='B'
  .....
  UNION
  SELECT
  'Z' as letter , 
  count(*) as total FROM totalCount
  WHERE left(UPPER(firstname),1)='Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another table

```
table_letter
id letter
1    A
2    B
3    C
...
26   Z

SELECT a.letter, COUNT(b.name) as total
FROM table_letter a
LEFT JOIN contacts b
ON a.letter = left(UPPER(b.name),1)
GROUP BY a.letter
```